# How can I obtain from QtObjects(lineedit,combobox)?

Tags: c++, qt

[image]

I generated QWidget QTGui objects with for(int i=0; i< Number;i++=) algorithm. So I can't get all Qtgui objects information When I changed something on the Widget. It gives only the last "i" value parameters. I need to get for i=0  all the parameters in one QString. After i=1 take to all parameters.

Like this:

```
i=0 1.Runner distance ,percentage = %80 Place = ComboBoxValue 
i=1 1.Runner distance ,percentage = %60 Place = ComboBoxValue
```

When I changed combobox or Percentage value. Finally, I want to take the percentage and comboBox value. 
Like this:

QString Runner1= QString(_Numberlabel->text() + label->text() + lineEdit->text() + comboBox->currentText());
 QString Runner2= QString(_Numberlabel->text() + label->text() + lineEdit->text() + comboBox->currentText());

```
enter code here

for(int i=0; i < runnerList.size() ;i++)
{
Layout = new QHBoxLayout();
Layout->setSpacing(6);
_Numberlabel= new QLabel();
_Numberlabel->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("_Numberlabel"));
_Numberlabel->setText(QString("First Runner").arg(i+1).arg(runnerList[i][0]).arg(runnerList[i][1]));

 QFont font;
 font.setFamily(QString::fromUtf8("Calibri"));
 font.setPointSize(10);
 font.setBold(true);
 font.setWeight(75);
 _Numberlabel->setFont(font);

 Layout->addWidget(_Numberlabel);

 label = new QLabel();
 label->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label"));
 label->setMaximumSize(QSize(60, 16777215));
 label->setFont(font);
 label->setText("Percantage:");
 Layout->addWidget(label);

 lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
 lineEdit->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("lineEdit"));
 lineEdit->setMaximumSize(QSize(50, 16777215));
 lineEdit->setText("%");

 Layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
 comboBox = new QComboBox();
 comboBox->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("comboBox"));
 comboBox->setMinimumSize(QSize(0, 25));
 comboBox->setMaximumSize(QSize(90, 16777215));
 comboBox->addItem("1");
 comboBox->addItem("2");
 comboBox->addItem("3");
 comboBox->addItem("4");
 Layout->addWidget(comboBox);
 this->ui.verticalLayout->addLayout(Layout);
 }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! What is `QtModules`?

Comment: At first glance I don't see where you get the data from your QLineEdit and QComboBox. Please paste a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added a new picture inside the question. I want to get data like a QString last = QString(_Numberlabel->text() + label->text() + lineEdit->text() + comboBox->currentText());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **either** need to keep handles to the objects you created:

```
// definition:
QList<QLineEdit*> lineEdits;
QList<QComboBox*> combos;
```

These lists should be class members.

```
// usage:
for(int i=0; i < runnerList.size() ;i++)
{
    //...
    lineEdits << lineEdit;
    combos << comboBox;
}
```

Then, you can get the values later on:

```
... = QString(lineEdits[i]->text() + combos[i]->currentText());
```

**Or** you could find them by their unique object name:

```
ui.verticalLayout->findChild<QLineEdit*>(QString("lineEdit_%1").arg(i))->text();
// I didn't try to compile this code!
```

For this you need to give each `QLineEdit` / `QComboBox` a unique object name.

**Or** you search for all `QLineEdit`s and hope that their order is well-defined:

```
ui.verticalLayout->findChildren<QLineEdit*>("lineEdit")[i]->text();
```

Disclaimer: This is all very ugly, but you should be able to see how it works.

Regardless of your choice, be aware:

Your line

```
_Numberlabel->setText(QString("First Runner").arg(i+1).arg(runnerList[i][0]).arg(runnerList[i][1]));
```

contains an error, because your `QString(...)` doesn't contain placeholders `%1`, `%2`, ..., but is followed by `.arg()` calls. That won't do anything except create a warning on the console.

Comment: Martin Thanks , You 've been very helpful. You are the King.

Comment: No, I'm not :-), but I'm glad I could be of help.